# Minted: am I using illegal characters?

Tags: characters, minted

I have the following simple LaTeX document...

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
  colorlinks=false,
  pdfborder={0,0,0},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{bash}
  #!/bin/bash
  curl -o wdbc.data http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data
  perl -ne '@f = split/,/; print(join(",", @f[2..31]))' < wdbc.data > wdbc-values.data
  perl -ne '@f = split/,/; printf("%s\n", $f[1])' < wdbc.data > wdbc-diagnoses.data
  /Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay < run-kmeans.m
  echo -e "\n\n\n======Results======"
  paste -d: wdbc-clusters.data wdbc-diagnoses.data | sort | uniq -c
\end{minted}


\end{document}
```

I've essentially copied the example from the minted home page and inserted a shell script. When I try to typeset this example, I get the following error.

```
standage@gremlin4:~hw04$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, pinyin, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/geometry.cfg)) (./minted.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty) (./test.w18)))/usr/bin/pygmentize

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty))
Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
*hyperref using default driver hpdftex*
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def) (./test.aux)
*geometry auto-detecting driver*
*geometry detected driver: pdftex*
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./test.pyg) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty)) (./test.out)
(./test.out) (./test.out.pyg
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
'->\leavevmode \kern \z@ 
                         \char `\'
l.5 ...o}{-}\PY{n}{diagnoses}\PY{p}{.}\PY{n}{data}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

If I replace the bash script with other code (Perl, R, etc), I have no problems. Does my bash script use characters that are not supported in minted? Is this documented anywhere?

**Note**:

```
>>> pygments = __import__('pygments', {}, {}, ['lexers', 'styles', 'formatters'])
>>> print 'Pygments', pygments.__version__
Pygments 1.3.1
```

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is the mathescape flag. Removing it worked for me, although according to minted documentation math is only rendered in comments. Could this be a bug in minted?

Comment: I notice that your version of `minted` is in the current directory. You may have a version mismatch: which version of `minted` are you using? (The example is Works For Me using an up to date TeX Live 2011 and Pygments.)

Comment: minted simply dispatches the handling of mathescape. This bug is either in Pygments (either in the lexer or the formatter) or in fancyvrb. I’ve just had a look at the relevant parts in the source code of Pygments and I’m unable to find an obvious bug. The `$` *is* properly escaped, and should be unable to trigger math mode.

Comment: That said, what version of Pygments are you using? If I remember correctly, earlier versions of Pygments had this bug.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I installed the python-pygments package on Ubuntu, so I assumed it was the most up-to-date version. I did realize that I am using this on Ubuntu 10.10 (my server; my desktop has the most up-to-date release), so maybe that has something to do with it. How do you check the pygments version?

Comment: Looks like I'm using version 1.3.1.

Comment: @Daniel The current version appears to be 1.5. You can install it using `pip` or `easy_install`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Removing `apt-get`'s pygments 1.3.1 and installing Pygments 1.5 with `easy_install` solved this problem. If you provide a short answer as to what the problem may have been, you're welcome to my accept vote. An update to the documentation might be in order, as it mentions that `minted` should work with pygments 1.3+.

Comment: @Daniel Done. I’ll update the documentation as soon as I find time (source is on another computer and a’tha’).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Pygments is outdated, and had a bug that was subsequently fixed. Updating Pygments should fix the problem. The easiest way to update  Pygments is to use `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pygments
```

(`pip` itself can be installed via `easy_install pip`, which, in turn, requires `easy_install` to be installed …)